# How can I group by this table?

Tags: mysql, group-by

could someone tell my how I could make this, please with MySQL statement?

Table input:

```
    col1   col2    col3
     B              C
     A      D    
     A              E
```

Output should be:

```
    line 1:  B              C
    line 2:  A      D       E
```

THe maximal rows for every input line in INPUT Table is 2. (here you see it with A)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example you show, this would work:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2), MAX(col3)
FROM InputTable
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. MAX does the trick. Cool. I tried a 14 line statment. THANKS